# Data type Object is not supported by Postgres database. NestJS

Tags: postgresql, nestjs

```
@Column({ nullable: true })
Test: number | string;
```

Why is the above returning an object? The data type can be either `string` or `number`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Column({ type: 'character varying' || 'integer', nullable: true })
Test: number | string;
```

The above made it work.